# Redraw SVG map on display of hidden div (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, svg

I'm trying to set up a responsive SVG map using a plugin called "Interactive World Maps" in Wordpress, but I want the map to be displayed only after the user clicks an element on the page to open a popup in which the map will appear.

The plugin I'm using redraws the map dynamically when the viewport is resized, and works just fine if the popup (really just a fixed-position div with a box shadow) is set to display on page load, but for some reason it's drawing the map in a much smaller size than the div it opens in onclick. What I want it to do is either load the svg or shortcode (and have it fill the div) only after clicking, or set the map to load in the proper size from the start.

I've tried setting the div to a width in px, but that didn't work. Don't know what else to do.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your PHP plugin is generating JS code that creates the map after the page loads.

If the container is visible it calculates its dimensions and set the size of the map accordingly.

But if the container is a hidden popup it can't calculate the correct dimensions for two possible reasons:

- The container is hidden by `style.display = "none"`: the element will have 0 width and height. The map appears so small because it takes the default minimum size.
- The container is hidden by `style.visibility = "hidden"` or `opacity: 0` (so it has actual dimensions) but its initial size is small; it grows when it is shown, to adapt to the page.

Check the the documentation of your plugin to see if you can call the function that generates the map not on page load but under an user's event. Depending on the API of your plugin it can be easy or cumbersome.

As a workaround, since the map adapts to the viewport, trigger a resize inside the handler of the `click` event that opens the popup. Something like:

```
var buttonThatOpensPopUp = document.getElementById( "buttonThatOpensPopUp" );
buttonThatOpensPopUp.addEventListener( function(){
  // here the code that opens popup...
  // then trigger resize
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The div was set to display:none; and the javascript I wrote to display it set it to display:block. Because of your advice, I instead set it to visibility:hidden and adjusted the javascript to match. Works like a charm!

Comment: @Benzy - Now that you are editing the question. It would be nice if you add the name of the plugin. It can be useful for future readers.

Comment: Sure thing. Hope it becomes helpful.